# How to make an Angular Material expandable table responsive

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, material-design-lite

I am trying to make my angular material expandable table responsive like [this StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-table-responsive-strict-mode?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmat-table-responsive%2Fmat-table-responsive.directive.scss,src%2Fapp%2Fmat-table-responsive%2Fmat-table-responsive.directive.ts) but that doesn't work as well since mine is an expandable table and turns out like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-table-responsive-strict-mode-ls8opf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmaterial-module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.css) and I am not sure how the demo works so if someone can help me modify it to work with my usage that'd be very appreciated if I can remove the blank name row in between and make it function like the full-screen size that'd be perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `td.mat-cell:not(.mat-column-actions)` to `td.mat-cell:not(.mat-column-actions, .mat-column-expandedDetail)` in the mat-table-responsive.directive.scss file removed the blank name row in between.

From:
[image: Before change]
To:
[image: After change]